# Steady State Error of controlled loop system

Tags: steady-state

I am trying to calculate the steady state error of the following system but unable to do it. I have used MATLAB and calculated the steady state error to be 0.1128 but don't understand the steps that I need to do to calculate this.

Please help.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you proceed :

1. Reduce the system to either unity feedback system or a Single block representing the closed loop transfer function. In your case, reducing to a single block should be easy.
2. For a unity feedback system , as shown

   [image]

Then from the diagram

```
E(s) = R(s) - Y(s) = R(s) - G(s)E(S)
```

Or

```
E(s) = R(s) / [ 1 + G(s)]
```

If you reduce it to a single block, Then

```
E(s) = R(s) - R(s)G(s) = R(s)[ 1 - G(s)]
```

If you have non unity feedback system, then

```
G'(s) = G(s) / [ 1 + G(s)H(s) - G(s)]
```

will reduce it to the form in figure.

3. For steady state error, you need to specify the input. 3 inputs are used :

   - Step with Laplace transform 1/s
   - Ramp with Laplace transform 1/s^2
   - Parabolic with Laplace transform 2/s^3
4. Substitute the transform of input into the equation for your error obtained in step 2.
5. Use the final value theorem acc to which

`E(infinity) = lim s-> 0 [ s.E(s)]`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have followed your steps and did the following: 1/s(1-700s+700/S^4+19.5s^3+99.5s^2+117s+736), then i did E(infinity) = lim s-> 0 [ 1-700/736]= 0.04891. Which is not correct.

Comment: Oh sorry forget to mention K = 0.375.

Comment: I done it again with gain k=0.375 and I get 0.1206 but I should get 0.1128.

Comment: I've found my mistake (and trying to correct it, will update soon). Maybe I should stop answering unless I am 1000 % sure :/

Comment: I used this source http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_Ess and my textbook. If that doesnt solve the problem either, please uncheck the answer so I can remove it. Either way, apologies for incorrect info.